# Display wordpress post's in popup?

Tags: plugins, posts, jquery, ajax

I am developing a wordpress site with some blogs.Each blog post will have an **READ MORE** link.when clicking the **READ MORE** it should open a popup box with that post contents. Can any one suggest me on how to get this.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7526740/1237290 Also, this is similar to the requirement you have: http://stanhub.com/load-wordpress-post-content-with-ajax-and-jquery/

Comment: @Subharanjan Thanks for sharing the tutorials. I have followed steps the posts are displaying but the popup is not displaying? i have added the jquery files as well.

Comment: You need to use some jQuery popup plugins. Shre your code what you have done so far, may be someone will help